# Create Pip package dependent on Shared Library

Tags: python, c++, swig

I have a C++ project that I have successfully created a Python binding for using Swig. I am able to create a Pip installation for the Python binding of my overall project but it is failing to copy the shared object needed for the binding to work.

When creating a Python binding for a C++ project with Swig there is a shared library created as well as a .py file that acts as the callable definitions for the Python API (think of it as a ).

Here is an example of what my setup.py file looks like:

```py
import setuptools

setuptools.setup(
    name='example',
    version='0.0.1',
    author='me',
    description='brief description',
    keywords='example, pypi, package',
    long_description=long_description,
    long_description_content_type='text/markdown',
    url='repo.com',
    project_urls={
        'Documentation': 'docs.com',
        'Bug Reports':'repo/issues.com',
        'Source Code': 'repo.com',
    },
    # location of Python API related files 
    package_dir={'': 'Python'},
    packages=setuptools.find_packages(where='Python'),
    package_data={'': ['path/to/_example.so']},
    classifiers=[
        # see https://pypi.org/classifiers/
        'Development Status :: 5 - Production/Stable',
        
        'Intended Audience :: Developers',
        'Topic :: Software Development :: Build Tools',
        
        'Programming Language :: Python :: 3',
        'Programming Language :: Python :: 3.6',
        'Programming Language :: Python :: 3.7',
        'Programming Language :: Python :: 3.8',
        'Programming Language :: Python :: 3.9',
        'Programming Language :: Python :: 3.10',
        'Programming Language :: Python :: 3 :: Only',
        'Operating System :: OS Independent',
    ],
    python_requires='>=3.6',
)
```

How can I modify my setup.py file to include the Swig binding creation process that creates a Pip package out of my project.